# Writing to an SQL Server

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to write a data frame to Microsoft SQL Server using the pandas `to_sql` function.

I have created an engine using

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
  'mssql:///Server/Database?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
)

switchers.to_sql('check',engine)
```

The error I am getting is as follows :

> OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (2)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Any idea what I should be looking for?

Comment: `conn = engine.connect()` and pass the connection in to_sql like: `switchers.to_sql('check',conn)`

Comment: Still getting the same error mate.